# flex 4.6 counting rows in sqlite table

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sqlite

This one is driving me mad for the last 3 hours. I want to check there are no records in an existing sqlite table:

```
...    
stmt.text = "SELECT id FROM customers";
stmt.execute();
var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;

if(result.length == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
```

The customer table exists but is empty. While running it flex gives this error on result.length:

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Comment: When there are records available in the table I get no error at all. I really don't understand this. result.data == null also gives this error....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Flex API doc for [SQLResult#data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html#data):

> If a statement does not return any data this property is null

You can't check for the length of an Array on `null`.  Therefore, your statement should read:

```
if (result == null) return 1;
```